# How do I change the value of a Hidden element?

Tags: 8

I would like to change the value of a hidden element and, depending of this value, to show some elements in the form or not. I'm trying to implement `hook_yamlform_element_info_alter(array &$elements)` and I do `$elements['hidden_element_name']['#value'] = 'New value of the hidden element'` but it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: `hook_element_info_alter()` alters definitions for form element types, but does not alter forms itself. `hook_form_alter()` alters a form before it is preprocessed and rendered.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @mradcliffe!! Finally, I've implemented `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` and I do `$form['elements']['hidden_element_name']['#value'] = 'New value of the hidden element';`. It works for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @mradcliffe suggestion, I've implemented `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` and I do:

```
$form['elements']['hidden_element_name']['#value'] = 'New value of the hidden element';
```

It works for me! I hope it helps someone!